# Changing value of a variable effects another variable

Tags: php, datetime, object, reference

everyone. I am new to PHP. I am having this problem with `DateTime`:

```
  $t1 = new DateTime();
  $t1->setTime(9, 30);
  $t2 = $t1;
  $t2->add (new DateInterval('PT10M'));
  echo $t1->format('H:i'); # outputs 9:40
```

As you can see, by changing the value of `$t2`, I also changed the value of `$t1`, which is not what I want. Would you please tell me why is this happening, and how to avoid it. Thank you.

Ian

Comment: Because they're the same value: `$t2 = $t1`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`$t1` and `$t2` are just reference to an object. When you do `$t1 = $t2`, you are just copying the reference, not the object.

You could to `$t1 = clone $t2` instead.

Comment: Thank you, I figured as much. Didn't know what to do, though.

Answer (score 0):

You should use

```
$t2 = clone $t1;
```

Answer (score 0):

You are causing $t2 to point to $t1. So editing $t2 causes you to edit the memory of $t1.

Use clone instead: $t2 = clone $t1

Comment: Both are a reference to the same object, but editing $t2 does not change $t1, it only changes the object $t1 is pointing to :)